# 8 bit input giving strange behavior as 16/32 bit gives for little Endian/Big Endian

Tags: c, pointers, struct, network-programming, bit-manipulation

I have a C structure like this ...

```
struct icmp_prefixopt {
    u_int8_t        icmpopt_type;
    u_int8_t        icmpopt_len;
    u_int8_t        prefixlen;
    u_int8_t        lflag:1;
    u_int8_t        aflag:1;
    u_int8_t        reserved:6;

};
```

and I have provided values to members like this in same module-

```
   popt= (struct icmp_prefixopt *)
                    malloc(sizeof(struct icmp_prefixopt));

  popt->icmpopt_type = 3;
  popt->icmpopt_len = 4;
  popt->prefixlen = (u_int8_t)strtoul(arg, (char **)NULL, 0);

     arg = index(arg, '+');
            if (arg) {
                    ++arg;
                    popt->lflag = ((u_int8_t)strtoul(arg, (char **)NULL, 0))&1;
            }


     arg = index(arg, '+');
            if (arg) {
                    ++arg;
                    popt->aflag = ((u_int8_t)strtoul(arg, (char **)NULL, 0))&1;
            }


     arg = index(arg, '+');
            if (arg) {
                    ++arg;
                 popt->reserved = 32;  //((u_int8_t)strtoul(arg, (char **)NULL, 0))<<2;
            }
```

where arg is command line argument passed to this module.

Now looking at the contents of structure after execution in hex format ->

```
  03 04 20 81

   icmpopt_type: seems fine
   icmpopt_len: seems fine
   prefixlen: seems fine
```

but bits looks like reversed for other 3 fields in their constitute byte-

```
  lflag:1; aflag:1; reserved:6
```

so it should have been - `10100000=A0` but actually they are `=>81=10000001`

It arise many questions to me ...

1. Is there anything to do with little endian/big endian?
2. If yes, what is the counterpart for functions like htonl and htons for 8 bit.
3. If no, what may be the possible issue or have I misunderstood something completely ?
4. What is best approach ? To modify order of these fields within the structure
   itself or applying some bit wise operator and shifting of bits here itself?

The input provided at command line-

```
    32+1+0+32
```

This final 32 serves no purpose here,as I have fixed 32 in module itself for testing.
Although my actual purpose needs to consider this field also.

Please help me soon with any alternative approach.

Thanx in advance.

**Edit:**

[image]

This is the actual structure I need to create and along with creating, need to made a provision for users to specify values for all the fields through GUI. (Right now only through linux command line).

I guess I have made the problem more clear now but still if any further information is required, I would be much happy to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How the compiler chooses to pack bit-fields is completely implementation-dependent.  It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with endianness.

`htnol` (and similar) don't apply to bit-fields.  If you need a guaranteed order, then you will need to manually pack a `uint8_t` yourself.  For example:

```
struct icmp_prefixopt {
    u_int8_t        icmpopt_type;
    u_int8_t        icmpopt_len;
    u_int8_t        prefixlen;
    u_int8_t        stuff;
}

...

popt->stuff = (lflag << 7) | (aflag << 6);
```

Of course, in practice, you should use sensible `#define`s rather than magic numbers (for 6 and 7).  And you may decide to wrap this in a bunch of setter and getter functions.

Comment: thanks ... as I am a begineer so can you also provide with some standard code snippet example or any relevant link that can help me to deal with more complex problems like these further ... as you said using `#define`s

Comment: Given standard's the lack of specificity in defining bit-field behavior, I find myself wondering what purpose they serve.  If one could declare something like `union SignFlag = StatusWord:7:1`, I could see that as being very useful both inside and outside structures (the syntax and `union` keyword chosen such that they can't possibly have any pre-existing meaning), combining the advantages of bitfields with real portability.  Too bad I doubt anyone will ever implement such a thing.